Recipe CommentOutSpringPropertyKey throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
I'm trying to use a recipe:
- org.openrewrite.java.spring.CommentOutSpringPropertyKey:
      propertyKey: spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit
      comment: "Use Oracle JDBC driver connection property autoCommit."

But when running the I get the following error:
"src/main/resources/application.yaml","org.openrewrite.java.spring.CommentOutSpringPropertyKey","java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.openrewrite.yaml.CommentOutProperty.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'
  org.openrewrite.java.spring.CommentOutSpringPropertyKey.getVisitor(CommentOutSpringPropertyKey.java:53)
  org.openrewrite.scheduling.RecipeRunCycle.lambda$editSources$7(RecipeRunCycle.java:178)
  org.openrewrite.scheduling.RecipeStack.reduce(RecipeStack.java:57)
  org.openrewrite.scheduling.RecipeRunCycle.lambda$editSources$8(RecipeRunCycle.java:155)
  org.openrewrite.internal.InMemoryLargeSourceSet.lambda$edit$0(InMemoryLargeSourceSet.java:66)
  org.openrewrite.internal.ListUtils.map(ListUtils.java:243)
  org.openrewrite.internal.ListUtils.map(ListUtils.java:265)
  org.openrewrite.internal.InMemoryLargeSourceSet.edit(InMemoryLargeSourceSet.java:65)
  org.openrewrite.scheduling.RecipeRunCycle.editSources(RecipeRunCycle.java:154)"

I'm using org.openrewrite.java.spring.ChangeSpringPropertyValue, org.openrewrite.java.spring.AddSpringProperty without any issues. For example:
  - org.openrewrite.java.spring.ChangeSpringPropertyValue:
      propertyKey: spring.datasource.driver-class-name
      newValue: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

I don't believe this is a classpath problem, but I can certainly be wrong? My pom.xml looks like this:
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.46.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <exportDatatables>true</exportDatatables>
                    <activeRecipes>
                        <recipe>com.oracle.spring.hikaritoucp</recipe>
                    </activeRecipes>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.openrewrite</groupId>
                        <artifactId>rewrite-java</artifactId>
                        <version>8.41.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
                        <artifactId>rewrite-spring</artifactId>
                        <version>5.24.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>


That recipe was changed last week: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-spring/commit/6738e13197a3f734fc9608f38349ebe3b4d27761
You'll want to either use the latest rewrite-spring SNAPSHOT or downgrade your Maven plugin to v5.46.1, until the next release (likely tomorrow).

I tried this but no luck         

org.openrewrite.maven
rewrite-maven-plugin
5.47.0-SNAPSHOT
...

We'll do a new release tomorrow; that should then likely help
